# Should I answer an existing old question or ask/answer my own new question?

Tags: discussion, answers, asking-questions

Is there a point when a question gets too old to answer it? Before today, there was no easy way to tell if your iOS device is currently jailbroken, but an iOS security analyst has developed an application you can install that will run all the technical checks it needs to determine if you are jailbroken. There is a very old question about telling if your device is jailbroken here: [How can I tell if my iOS device is currently jailbroken?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70809/how-can-i-find-out-if-my-iphone-is-jailbroken)

That question has been answered already and has an accepted answer basically saying that you just check to see if Skype works or not (a very old method to check for jailbreaks that hasn't worked for years).

Should I answer this existing question or ask my own? Are there any general guidelines on this sort of thing?

Comment: Does the new way only work on certain versions of IOS and does the old way again work for versions or has just time broken things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [best answer I could find comes from Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202900/answering-a-duplicate-question-with-a-more-current-answer?). It basically says that I should post my answer to the older question since it's been around longer and has attention already.

Comment: Yes, I agree with the Meta.SE post. Unless the older question restricts answers in a certain way (e.g, OS X version restriction) you should answer the original question.

Comment: +1 on editing / updating / refreshing a new answer to an existing question. If it turns out that your answer there isn't totally on topic - you can always ask a new question (or find a newer question to answer) after trying to keep the details together. Unless there's a significant change - say the old question was Mac OS 9 and the new one Mac OS 10 - would a split of the same topic make sense to ask a new question.